# Call multiple triggers

Tags: javascript, animation, frontend, gsap

I have code like this:

```
function App() {
  const [first, setFirst] = useState(false)
  const [second, setSecond] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

    gsap.to('.first', {
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: '.first',

        start: 'top top+=150',
        markers: { startColor: "green", endColor: "yellow", fontSize: "12px" },
        onEnter: () => {
            setFirst(true)
        }
      }
    })
    gsap.to('.second', {
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: '.second',
        start: 'top top+=150',
        markers: { startColor: "green", endColor: "yellow", fontSize: "12px" },
        onEnter: () => {
            setSecond(true)
        }
      }
    })
  })

  return (
    <div>
        <First first={first} />
        <Second second={second} />

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Components First and Second are simple. UseEffect hook looks like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(props.first === true){
        //animate
    }
})
```

I can activate First animation but if I activate Second, First animation animate again. Do you have idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Using `setState` inside `useEffect` can cause an infinite loop specially if you are not specifying dependencies (second argument).

`useEffect` the way you are using it, runs after your component is rendered no matter what caused the rendering or re-rendering.
`setState` causes a re-render and triggers `useEffect` again.

I suggest you re-architecture your app to run `setFirst(true)` and `setSecond(true)` outside `useEffect`

Or do something like this:

```
onEnter: () => animation.play(),
onLeave: () => animation.pause(),
```

Or use a [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger)

Here is an example of an app using React + GSAP 3
https://github.com/npinos/cloud-animations-react-gsap